# how can I dynamically insert/change svg stylesheet ref?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have an SVG which I'm importing into a web page from an external file via an object tag. The following reference works in my local environment:

```XML
<?xml-stylesheet href="../css/app.min.css" type="text/css"?>
```

However, my code is being deployed to an environment with a different directory structure. Therefore, I need a way to programmatically set or change the href path above via d3.js. After the SVG is loaded it will trigger a js function which needs to set or update the href path to a path value which has been configured in the parent app instance.

Please describe the technical implementation options that I could use to accomplish this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createProcessingInstruction

Comment: Here's some more insight into the CDT watch vals for my scenario:

rootElement: svg

parentNode.childNodes:

0: xml-stylesheet
1: comment
2: <!DOCTYPE svg>
3: svg

So I've identified an object handle for xml-stylesheet but xml-stylesheet is a complex object so I'm tyring to figure out the best way to set the href prop to the new url. Other same-level attrs within xml-stylesheet will also need to be modified. I'm wondering if there's some type of existing function I can use which will encapsulate the logic to ensure that related props are updated as needed.